# How do i refer to any image in my java web application from root of my web application?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a folder named `Common/Images/Photounavailable.jpg`. Is this right way of refering to a image from root? I want to refer this image from any page in any folder in my web application.

```
private String getPhotoUnavailablePath = "/Common/Images/PhotoNotAvailable.jpg";
    private String getPhotoUnavailablePath(){
        return photoUnavailablePath;
    }
```

And from my JSF page i write something like :-

```
<h:outputLink id ="blogPhoto" value="#{BlogBean.photoUnavailablePath}" >
  <h:graphicImage value="#{BlogBean.photoUnavailablePath}" style="width: 180px;height: 180px;"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

I get the image to see in h:graphicImage. But when i click on it, i get 404 error. OutputLink doesn't get proper link to image. How is it possible? That h:graphicImage gets proper link and h:outputLink doesn't?

Further, this code works perfectly :-

```
<h:outputLink id ="blogPhoto" value="..#{BlogBean.photoUnavailablePath}" >
  <h:graphicImage value="#{BlogBean.photoUnavailablePath}" style="width: 180px;height: 180px;"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

Just by putting `..` it works! Can anybody explain me what is happening and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<h:graphicImage>` uses context-relative paths.
`<h:outputLink>` uses absolute paths. That's why you can't use the `/` (unless in the root context).

You can use something like

```
 value="#{facesContext.externalContext.context.contextPath}/#{bean.path}"
```

to specify that the start of the path is the context root, not the server root.